# Identificar quantidade de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas em uma string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso verificar se em uma palavra tem mais letras maiúsculas e substituir a palavra inteira para apenas letras minúsculas, também verificar se tem mais letras minúsculas e substituir a palavra inteira para maiúscula. Por exemplo, a palavra "HoUse" deve ser substituída por "house" e a palavra "LEgAL" por "LEGAL". Se uma palavra contém um número igual de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, deve-se substituir todas as letras maiúsculas por minúsculas, como por exemplo a palavra "PaGoDe" deve ser substituída por "pagode". O que eu fiz, só retorna a palavra em minúsculas mas não em maiúsculas. O que eu tenho que mudar?

```
palavra = input()

if any(x.islower() for x in palavra) > any(x.isupper() for x in palavra):
    print(palavra.lower())
elif any(x.islower() for x in palavra) < any(x.isupper() for x in palavra):
    print(palavra.upper())
elif any(x.islower() for x in palavra) == any(x.isupper() for x in palavra):
    print(palavra.lower())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação de [`any`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#any):

> Retorna `True` se algum elemento de *iterable* for verdadeiro. Se *iterable* estiver vazio, retorna `False`.

Como essa função retorna um booleano, não faz sentido compará-los como você está fazendo em cada um dos três `if`s. Cada `any` simplesmente verifica se cada lista satisfaz, pelo menos uma vez, a condição do predicado.

Portanto, você deve *contar* quantas letras maiúsculas e quantas letras minúsculas essa mesma palavra tem, de modo a fazer a comparação uma vez que estiver em posse desses dois números.

Uma opção seria trocar o `any` por [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sum), que retorna a soma de todos os elementos da lista. A lista de *booleanos* é corretamente somada já que `boolean` é uma subclasse de `int` (o que significa que `True` equivale a `1` e `False`, a `0`). [Saiba mais aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479905/identificar-quantidade-de-letras-mai%C3%BAsculas-e-min%C3%BAsculas-em-uma-string/479906#comment899003_479906)

Nesse caso, teremos:

```
word = input("Uma palavra: ")

if sum(x.islower() for x in word) > sum(x.isupper() for x in word):
    print(word.lower())
elif sum(x.islower() for x in word) < sum(x.isupper() for x in word):
    print(word.upper())
elif sum(x.islower() for x in word) == sum(x.isupper() for x in word):
    print(word.lower())
```

O problema é que, só para fazer a contagem, teríamos que varrer a *string* duas vezes, uma para cada `sum`.

Se isso for um problema, você pode fazer uso de um contador, de modo a só iterar (para fazer a contagem) uma vez. Algo assim:

```
def count_casing(word):
    upper = lower = 0

    for char in word:
        if char.isupper():
            upper += 1
        elif char.islower():
            lower += 1

    return upper, lower


word = input("Uma palavra: ")

upper, lower = count_casing(word)
if upper > lower:
    print(word.upper())
else:
    print(word.lower())
```

Note que `upper` e `lower` também percorrem a *string* mais uma vez. Portanto, o código acima "varre" a *string* duas vezes.

Observe também que o último `if` (no caso da quantidade de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas serem iguais) não é necessário, já que o `else` cobre esse caso também. :)

Comment: Essa mania do JavaScript de criar objeto pra tudo :-) Em Python vc pode criar os contadores separadamente e retorná-los em uma tupla: https://ideone.com/tfTarV

Comment: @hkotsubo, realmente, fica bem mais sucinto sem o dicionário; foi de fato um _vício de linguagem_. :D Muito obrigado pela sugestão, editei a resposta.

Comment: Só para ser pedante, `sum` não converte booleanos em números. Na verdade, segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex), boolean **é** um sub-tipo de `int`, tanto que `isinstance(True, int)` retorna `True` (e `True` e `False` são equivalentes a respectivamente 1 e 0 - tanto que `True == 1` e `False == 0` são verdadeiros, e lembrando que Python não faz a coerção maluca do JS). Ver mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37888620) e [aqui](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibiliade seria "brincar" com funções e bibliotecas internas.

Vamos ver como funciona o `map` e classe `Counter`

### map

A função `map` aplica uma função a cada elemento de um objeto iterável. A sintaxe desta é':

> resultado = map(funcao, iteravel)

O resultado é do tipo `iterator`

### Counter

O `Counter` é usado para contar a frequência dos elementos em um iterável.

> c = Counter(iteravel)

Dito isto vamos à solução

```
# Carrega o método Counter da library collections
from collections import Counter

# Define a palavra
palavra = "PaGoDe"

# Identificando se a letra é minúscula ou maiúscula 
def identifica_case(letra):
    if letra.islower():
        return "l"
    elif letra.isupper():
        return "U"

# Criando o mapa
mapa = map(identifica_case, palavra)
```

Conforme dito anteriormente, o `map` retorna um iterator, caso queira ver o conteúdo do mesmo, pode apenas rodar um `print(list(mapa))`

O resultado deste referente à palavra `PaGoDe` seria:

> ['U', 'l', 'U', 'l', 'U', 'l']

```
c = Counter(mapa)
```

O print de `c` para este exemplo seria:

> Counter({'U': 3, 'l': 3})

```
maior_qtd = max([c["l"], c["U"]])

if c["U"] == maior_qtd:
    print(palavra.lower())
else:
    print(palavra.upper())
```

**Nota** O objetivo de criar a variável `maior_qtd`, por meio do `max`, se dá pelo fato da palavra poder conter outros caracteres (ex.: `"Python!!!!!!!!!!!!!"`)

**Nota** A classe `Counter` possui o método `most_common(N)`, mas acredito que neste caso não ajudaria. (`N` é a quantidade de itens que vc quer de retorno). Isso é muito usado para o `Top N`

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é implementar o seguinte código:

```
def forma_letras(v):

    upper = lower = 0
    for d in v:
        if d.isupper():
            upper += 1
        else:
            lower += 1

    if upper >= lower:
        return v.lower()
    return v.upper()


print(forma_letras(''.join(input('Digite uma palavra: '))))
```

Observe que quando executamos este código, devemos digitar uma palavra. A partir desse momento a string é passada como parâmetro para a função **forma_letras(v)**. Chegando lá, o bloco `for` percorrerá a referida string e, com ajuda do bloco **1º bloco if** verificará se a **letra** da respectiva interação é **upper**. Caso positivo, upper é incrementado. Caso negativo, lower é incrementado. Depois, o **2º bloco if** verificará se upper é maior ou igual a lower. Caso positivo, o retorno da função exibirá todas as letras em **minúsculas**. Caso negativo, o retorno da função exibirá todas as letras em **maiúsculas**.